# how to add divider between each row for Antd List component

Tags: list, antd

Im using Ant List for my project and i would like to add divider or separator between each row in List component not sure how to do it with Antd
this is codesandbox similar to my List
https://codesandbox.io/s/s233d

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have to add a divider. List component separates each item automatically with a line that looks like divider. I would get rid of 'grid' property on the list and update your list component:

```html
 <List 
    dataSource={data}
    renderItem={item => (
      <List.Item>
        <Card title={item.title}>Card content</Card>        
      </List.Item>

    )}
  />
```